# When an attribute of a struct is a pointer to another struct

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, struct

(Using C) 
If I wanted to call a given attribute of a struct, I simply use the notation struct.attribute. Sometimes, however, the attribute in question is a pointer to another struct. In this case I would use struct.pointer_to_struct. 
How, then, do I call an attribute of the struct that is being pointed to? It would seem logical to write: struct.pointer_to_struct->attribute, but the compiler doesn't accept this. 
Here's an example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct thing
{
        char gender[6];
        char name[21];
        struct thing **friends;
};

int main(void)
{
        struct thing things[3];

        strncpy(things[0].name, "Bob", 21);
        strncpy(things[1].name, "Kelly", 21);
        strncpy(things[1].gender, "Female", 6);

        things[0].friends = &things[1];

        printf("%s is friends with %s\n", things[0].name, things[0].friends->name);

        return 0;
}
```

The line printf("%s is friends with %s\n", things[0].name, things[0].friends->name); doesn't get compiled because of the things[0].friends->name.
I want to find some way of saying 'Bob is friends with Kelly' on the fly, when only coding with regard to Bob.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a "pointer to struct" but a "pointer to pointer(s) of struct", a.k.a. "pointer to an array of pointer(s) to struct(s)":

```
struct thing **friends;
```

Therefore you'd need to print

```
things[0].friends[0]->name
```

for the 1st friend, `friends[1]->name` for the 2nd and so on.

(But as you don't have any "number of friends" integer variable there, it might be hard to work with this. Also you are filling the variable in a wrong way, you would need to create an extra array with the individual pointers to friends somewhere, e.g. on the heap.)

Answer (score 0):

```
struct thing
{
        char gender[6];
        char name[21];
        struct thing **friends; // why thing **
};
```

it should be,

`struct thing *friends` and not `struct thing **friends`